# Add custom field to salesforce standard account via application?

Tags: salesforce

I need to add a custom field to the standard salesforce account object when a user installs my SalesForce application (Managed) in his organization.

Is it possible to package such customization into a managed package and distribute? I'm unable to find any reference to such packaging in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your managed package page:

1. Press the **Add** button under the Components tab.
2. Set the Component Type to Custom Field
3. Check the Checkbox next to your field
4. Press **Add To Package**

More details are available in the documentation under [Adding Components to Your Package](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=adding_package_components.htm&language=en_US).

Note that once your managed package is released certain details will be locked down and can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build-->Customize-->Account-->Fields

Scroll down to the Account Custom Fields and Relationships related list.

Click on the 'New' button and create a new field of the Account object.